# Attribute error while creating scope to access Azure Datalake Gen2 from Databricks

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2, databricks-connect

I was trying to setup using the scopes and I am having a few issues. Any help would be appreciated.

I ran the below commands in Databricks CLI

```
databricks secrets create-scope --scope dnb-dlg2-dbrcks-scp-stg
databricks secrets put --scope dnb-dlg2-dbrcks-scp-stg --key SPID --string-value "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
databricks secrets put --scope dnb-dlg2-dbrcks-scp-stg --key SPKey --string-value "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX”
databricks secrets put --scope dnb-dlg2-dbrcks-scp-stg --key DirectoryID --string-value "XXXXXXXXXX"
```

Successfully created the scope. Then I tried to run the below in my notebook

```
#Gather Relevant Keys from our scope

ServicePrincipalId=dbutils.secret.get(scope="dnb-dlg2-dbrcks-scp-stg",key="SPID")
ServicePrincipalKey=dbutils.secret.get(scope="dnb-dlg2-dbrcks-scp-stg",key="SPKey")
DirectoryID=dbutils.secret.get(scope="dnb-dlg2-dbrcks-scp-stg",key="DirectoryID")

#Combine DirectoryID into full string
Directory="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{}/oauth2/token".format(DirectoryID)

#Create configurations for our connections
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id" : ServicePrincipalId,
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret":  ServicePrincipalKey,
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": Directory}
# "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret" -> dbutils.secrets.get("dnb-dbrk-scrt-scp-stg", key = "dnb-data-bricks-kv-stg"),

# Mount the Data Lake onto DBFS at the /mnt/ location

dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "abfss://datastore@dbstgstoraccgen2.dfs.core.windows.net/",
  mount_point = "/mnt/datastore5",
  extra_configs = configs)
```

I get an error at this point .Please refer to the image below

[image: Error]

**ERROR DETAILS**

```
    AttributeError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-4345234368633882> in <module>
----> 1 dbutils.secret.get(scope="dnb-dlg2-dbrcks-scp-stg",key="SPID")

/local_disk0/tmp/1575916741583-0/dbutils.py in __getattr__(self, item)
    482             return self.credentials
    483 
--> 484         raise AttributeError
    485 
    486     def __repr__(self):

AttributeError:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small typo mistake in your code: "**secret**" should be "**secrets**".

[image]

**Error:**

```
ServicePrincipalId=dbutils.secret.get(scope="dnb-dlg2-dbrcks-scp-stg",key="SPID")
ServicePrincipalKey=dbutils.secret.get(scope="dnb-dlg2-dbrcks-scp-stg",key="SPKey")
DirectoryID=dbutils.secret.get(scope="dnb-dlg2-dbrcks-scp-stg",key="DirectoryID")
```

Replace "**secret.get**" with "**secrets.get**"

```
ServicePrincipalId=dbutils.secrets.get(scope="dnb-dlg2-dbrcks-scp-stg",key="SPID")
ServicePrincipalKey=dbutils.secrets.get(scope="dnb-dlg2-dbrcks-scp-stg",key="SPKey")
DirectoryID=dbutils.secrets.get(scope="dnb-dlg2-dbrcks-scp-stg",key="DirectoryID")
```

[image]

Hope this helps. Do let us know if you any further queries.

---

Do click on "Mark as Answer" and Upvote on the post that helps you, this can be beneficial to other community members.

Comment: Hi @kranny, Just checking in to see if the above answer helped. If this answers your query, do click “Mark as Answer” and Up-Vote for the same. And, if you have any further query do let us know.